# SCCM using an existing WSUS server

Tags: wsus, sccm

I currently have a WSUS 3.0 sp2 in the environment. I have just installed SCCM r2 sp2 and want it to use the existing wsus server. Is this an option if so doesn anyone know how this is done.
I have look in the site settings but it doesnt allow you to choose your wsus server.
Am I missing something simple?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you sure can, but there are some limitations... check out

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/configmgrsum/thread/79f57023-0e82-4c67-aa5a-15d0be2b4299

Comment: Thanks for the link quite helpful however is there a non drastic measure of setting up WSUS withour having to uninstall and and reinstall it? Can I just install it on my SCCM machine?